# listView with a countDownTimer's onFinish method issue

Tags: android, listview, countdowntimer

I've a problem with the "countDownTimer" that when I run two counters in two different rows in the listview , the "onfinish" function proceed for the last clicked row only ..

so, "onfinish" method makes the Dialog appears with the text of the last textview clicked.

but,I want that "onfinish" method show the dialog for the specific clicked row that finished counting.

this's the code

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecipeStepsActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int hours;
TextView fullTime;
TextView step;
String fullTimeString;
String[] fullTimeArray;
MediaPlayer myTen;
Activity context;
long init = 0, now;
AdapterView<?> parent1;
CountDownTimer x;
static boolean[] arr;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_steps);
    context = this;
    arr = new boolean[XmlHandler.HashMapOfTime.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = false;
    }
    System.out.println(XmlHandler.HashMapOfTime.size()
            + "++++++++++++++++++++++");
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);
    list.setAdapter(new RecipeStepsListAdapter(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_recipe_steps_list_adapter,
            XmlHandler.HashMapOfSteps.get(Main.position),
            XmlHandler.HashMapOfTime.get(Main.position)));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int newid,
                long arg3) {
            parent1 = parent;

            final String item = (String) parent1.getItemAtPosition(newid);
            fullTimeArray = new String[3];
            fullTimeArray = item.split(":");
            hours = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[0]);
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[1]);
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[2]);
            Long times = ((hours * 60L * 60L) + (minutes * 60L) + seconds) * 1000;


            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (i == newid && arr[newid] == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecipeStepsActivity.this, "Counter begin",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCounterDownTimer(times, newid);
                    arr[newid] = true;
                    break;
                } else if (i == newid && arr[newid] == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
                            "Counter stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    arr[newid] = false;
                    x.cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    });

}

public void createCounterDownTimer(final Long times, final int id) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            x = new CountDownTimer(times, 1000) {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onTick(long ms) {
            //      System.out.println("===");

                    fullTime = (TextView) findViewById(id);
                    step = (TextView) findViewById(id + 10);
                    System.out.println(step.getId()+" of the onTick step");
                    // step.setId(id);
                    System.out.println(step.getId()+" -------------------------"+step.getText()+"---------------------- ");
                    System.out.println(fullTime.getId()+" -------------------------"+fullTime.getText()+"---------------------- ");

                    int seconds = (int) (ms / 1000) % 60;
                    int minutes = (int) ((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                    int hours = (int) ((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
                     System.out.println(id+" ===> "+hours + ": " + minutes +
                     ": "
                     + seconds);
                    fullTime.setText(hours + ": " + minutes + ": "
                            + seconds);
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    fullTime.setText("time up!");
                    System.out.println(step.getId()+" finished id step");
                    System.out.println(fullTime.getId()
                            + " =============== " + fullTime.getText()
                            + "===" + step.getText());

                    myTen = MediaPlayer.create(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
                            R.raw.soundd);
                    myTen.start();
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            RecipeStepsActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("time up");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(fullTime.getText().toString()
                            + " is finished");
                    alertDialog.setButton("ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method
                                    // stub
                                    System.out.println(step.getId()+" onclick dialog finished id step");
                                    System.out.println("finished");
                                    myTen.stop();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }.start();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recipe_steps, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: you want dialog to be popped up each time a row is clicked ?, you you need it to be popped only once for the first clicked item?

Comment: no, there's a counter which countDown when I click on the raw ... and after the counter reach the value (0:0:0) the Dialog appears containing a text from a textview exists in the row ..

I need it appears for all the clicked rows when their counter reach (0)

Answer (score 0):

Alright, based on your requirement do this, much simpler and clean.

1. Create a Handler.
2. Upon clicking of a Row, drop a delayed message with time interval you want attaching text from textView of clicked row to handler, this will be executed by handler upon elapse of supplied time interval.
3. If you want to cancel any message, just call removeCallback from handler for particular callback you want to withdraw.
4. Write dialog popping code inside handleMessage block of handler, there you can pop a alert box with required message.

Hope it help.

Comment: thanks for your help , but if there's a code sample about that , it would be much understood :)  

I've solved the problem by a condition in the intick() method, check it if you don't mind and give me your feedback

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem by putting  a condition in the ontick() method

inside it I put a variable that would hold the value of the current counting ( step text ).
and I've used it in the onfinish() function .

this's the code

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecipeStepsActivity extends Activity {
ListView list;
int minutes;
int seconds;
int hours;
TextView fullTime;
TextView step;
String fullTimeString;
String[] fullTimeArray;
MediaPlayer myTen;
Activity context;
long init = 0, now;
AdapterView<?> parent1;
CountDownTimer x;
static boolean[] arr;

@SuppressLint("ShowToast")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_steps);
    context = this;
    arr = new boolean[XmlHandler.HashMapOfTime.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = false;
    }

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listId);
    list.setAdapter(new RecipeStepsListAdapter(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
            R.layout.activity_recipe_steps_list_adapter,
            XmlHandler.HashMapOfSteps.get(Main.position),
            XmlHandler.HashMapOfTime.get(Main.position)));

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int newid,
                long arg3) {
            parent1 = parent;

            final String item = (String) parent1.getItemAtPosition(newid);
            fullTimeArray = new String[3];
            fullTimeArray = item.split(":");
            hours = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[0]);
            minutes = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[1]);
            seconds = Integer.parseInt(fullTimeArray[2]);
            Long times = ((hours * 60L * 60L) + (minutes * 60L) + seconds) * 1000;

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                if (i == newid && arr[newid] == false) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecipeStepsActivity.this, "Counter begin",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    createCounterDownTimer(times, newid);
                    arr[newid] = true;
                    break;
                } else if (i == newid && arr[newid] == true) {
                    Toast.makeText(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
                            "Counter stopped", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    arr[newid] = false;
                    x.cancel();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
String temp ;
public void createCounterDownTimer(final Long times, final int id) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            x = new CountDownTimer(times, 1000) {

                @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                @Override
                public void onTick(long ms) {
            //      System.out.println("===");

                    fullTime = (TextView) findViewById(id);
                    step = (TextView) findViewById(id + 10);

                    int seconds = (int) (ms / 1000) % 60;
                    int minutes = (int) ((ms / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                    int hours = (int) ((ms / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);

                    fullTime.setText(hours + ": " + minutes + ": "
                            + seconds);

                    if(hours == 0 && minutes == 0 && seconds == 1){

                         temp = step.getText().toString();
                         fullTime.setText("time up!");
                    }
                }

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    myTen = MediaPlayer.create(RecipeStepsActivity.this,
                            R.raw.soundd);
                    myTen.start();
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                            RecipeStepsActivity.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("time up");
                    alertDialog.setMessage(temp
                            + " is finished");
                    //arrayyy.remove(0);
                    alertDialog.setButton("ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method
                                    myTen.stop();
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });

                    alertDialog.show();

                }

            }.start();

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.recipe_steps, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```